# ReactNative - ImageBackground load local image with a delay

Tags: react-native, imagebackground, delay-load

I noticed that, when I run the `react-native` app, the images that I set as background using the tag `<ImageBackground>` load with a delay of almost 2 seconds, even if they are not heavy images (~100K) and they are stored in local.

I have also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55538975/6608222) but it didn't solve my problem.

This is my simple code for insert an image as background:

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../images/ScanQR.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
    <Text style={styles.domanda}>
      Example text
    </Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can require() the images inside of App.js to load them before. Do it like this:

```js
async function loadResourcesAsync() {
  await Promise.all([
    Asset.loadAsync([
      require('./assets/images/stock1.jpg'),      
      require('./assets/images/stock2.jpg'), 
      require('./assets/images/undraw1.png'), 
    ]),
    Font.loadAsync({
      // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
      ...Ionicons.font,
      // We include SpaceMono because we use it in HomeScreen.js. Feel free to
      // remove this if you are not using it in your app      
      'open-sans-regular': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
      'open-sans-extrabold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    }),
  ]);
}
```

I am using Expo here and you don't need to create this function, it's already inside of App.js, just add your images inside of require() function.

I don't know if this would work in React Native without Expo.

Comment: Doing as you suggest the problem of uploading images is solved but in turn creates another. When a button is pressed, a moment is selected (~ 1 second) before moving to the next page

Answer (score 0):

Following [@crodev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57578468/2312298), but for people using React Function Components, you can use hooks to achieve same result.

Additionally, you can use [AppLoading](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/docs/pages/versions/unversioned/sdk/app-loading.md) component from `expo-app-loading` to keep splash screen until everything is ready.

```js
function useImages(images) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Asset.loadAsync(images)
      .then(() => setLoaded(true))
      .catch(setError);
  }, []);

  return [loaded, error];
}

export default function App() {
  const [imagesLoaded] = useImages([
      require('./assets/images/stock1.jpg'),      
      require('./assets/images/stock2.jpg'), 
      require('./assets/images/undraw1.png'), 
  ]);

  if (!imagesLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }
  
  return <>...</>;
}
```